# Split two columns by delimiter and merge together taking a step from each (EXCEL 2016)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Ok so I have two columns of data as follows

```
Personalisation Max Char | Personaisation Field
       1x15x25           | Initial, Name, Date
```

Previously I was using the following vba function (As excel16 has no TEXTJOIN)

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
Dim d As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim arr2()
Dim t As Long, y As Long
t = -1
y = -1
If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
    arr2 = arr.Value
Else
    arr2 = arr
End If
On Error Resume Next
t = UBound(arr2, 2)
y = UBound(arr2, 1)
On Error GoTo 0

If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
    For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
        For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
            If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
            End If
        Next d
    Next c
Else
    For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
            TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
        End If
    Next c
End If
TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

This would change `1x15x25` into `1-1, 2-15, 3-25`using the following formula

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x",""))+1)) & "  - " & TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x",""))+1)) -1)*999+1,999)))}
```

Due to the fact, my original method was not specific enough I've been forced to go back to the drawing board.

From the Above, I am wanting to produce the following.

1-2-Initial, 2-15-Name, 3-25-Date

I am a developer but not in visual basic and the worst part Is I know what I would do with a database and PHP just don't have enough knowledge to transfer that to excel.

So I need to either by formula or function

- Take 2 Columns and split by a delimiter
- Then count the entries on each (Maybe only one)
- Then for each in the range create a new string adding the count-col1-col2

I cannot change the data as its given by the supplier

I have a basic understanding of VBA so explain don't belittle

UPDATED (DATA SNAPSHOTS)
This Example uses the formula above a little-jazzed up.

As you can see each row starts the count again Ignore the Personalization/Message line parts I can add these again later

[image: My Previous Attempt]
[image: The Data im given]

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: So it should take `1x15x25` and `Initial,Name,Date` and the result would merge to 1-1-Initial, 2-15-Name, 3-25-Date.     The first part of each is the count from col 1, the second is from col 1, the third col 2

Comment: Could you show the expected output for say 2 or 3 rows so I can see how the rules are applied for more than 1 row? Do you join all together in one string? Do you re-start  prefix numbering from 1 on next row or continue incrementing from end of last row etc...

Comment: And you have done well if this is a beginner effort.

Comment: How many rows are there? - is it viable to do a `for...loop` to cycle through each row? My first inclination to make it as simple as possible is to just run a routine to go through each

Comment: There are 6000+ rows ill upload a snapshot of the data I have and what I had so far

Comment: Im hoping to do a for loop as that is what I would do in PHP. YES the values in col1 and 2 should match in values so if there are 1x2x3 there should be 1,2,3 and I add a default value if they do not match for condition formating to pick up on later

Answer (score 0):

I am in a mega rush so only whipped this up with one row of values (in A1 and B1)

I hope you can step through to understand it, wrap it in another loop to go through your 6000 rows, and change the msgbox to whatever output area you need... 6000 rows should be super quick:

```
Sub go()
Dim a() As String
Dim b() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String

' split A1 and B1 based on their delimiter, into an array a() and b()
a() = Split(Range("A1").Value2, "x")
b() = Split(Range("B1").Value2, ",")

' quick check to make sure arrays are same size! 
If UBound(a) <> UBound(b) Then Exit Sub

' this bit will need amended to fit your needs but I'm using & concatenate to just make a string with the outputs
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(b)
    str = str & i + 1 & "-" & a(i) & "-" & b(i) & vbNewLine
Next i

' proof in the pudding
MsgBox str

End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask why Sub() instead of Function() is function not the only thing that will return a value ?

Comment: Sorry yeah you can use a function to return a single value, but a routine can just paste values directly in to whatever cell you want. In my answer you could swap the line MsgBox str to just the function name = str e.g. `go = str` - like I said, this was a super quick answer cos I was leaving but hope it helped somewhat

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set rngDB = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) '<~~personaliation Max Char data range
    ReDim vR(1 To rngDB.Count, 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To rngDB.Count
        vR(i, 1) = textjoin(rngDB(i), rngDB(i, 2))
    Next i
    Range("c2").Resize(rngDB.Count) = vR '<~ result wil be recorded in Column C

End Sub

Function textjoin(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    Dim vS1, vS2
    Dim vR()
    Dim i As Integer
    vS1 = Split(rng1, "x")
    vS2 = Split(rng2, ",")
    ReDim vR(UBound(vS1))
    For i = LBound(vS1) To UBound(vS1)
        vR(i) = i + 1 & "-" & Trim(vS1(i)) & "-" & Trim(vS2(i))
    Next i
    textjoin = Join(vR, ",")
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**THANK YOU FOR ALL OF THE HELP**

I went back to the drawing board having seen the above.

I learnt

- That my original use of array formula and TEXTJOIN where over the top and hardly simplistic
- That I can use VBA just like any other programming code :)

My Solution simplified from [Dy.Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8107092/dy-lee)

```
Function SPLITANDMERGE(arr1 As String, arr2 As String, Optional del1 As String = "x", Optional del2 As String = ",")
    'Arr1 Split'
    Dim aS1

    'Arr2 Split'
    Dim aS2

    'Value Array'
    Dim r()

    'Value Count'
    Dim v As Integer

    'Split The Values'
    aS1 = Split(arr1, del1)
    aS2 = Split(arr2, del2)

    'Count The Values'
    ReDim r(UBound(aS1))

    'For All The Values'
    For v = LBound(aS1) To UBound(aS2)

        'Create The String'
        r(v) = "Personalisation_Line " & v + 1 & " - " & Trim(aS1(v)) & " Characters - [" & Trim(aS2(v)) & "]"

    Next v

    'Join & Return'
    SPLITANDMERGE = Join(r, ", ")

End Function
```

I'm still working on it but I now get the following result.

Will Be Adding:

- Value Count Comparison (If we have 4 and 5 Values return "-" to be picked up by conditional formatting)
- Conditional plural values (If value 2 in the string is 0 then character instead of characters

If there are any pitfalls or errors anyone can see please do enlighten me. Im here to learn.

[image: The Result]